# How to access parent text which has no tag through xPath

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Please find the code below

```
<div class="xsmall-12 medium-6 columns">
                        <label class="device-attribute-label" rel="tooltip" title="Proprietary/trade name of the medical device as used in the labeling or catalog.">Brand Name:</label>
                        Snowden-Pencer
                        <br>
                        <label class="device-attribute-label" rel="tooltip" title="Identifies a category or design of devices that have specifications, performance, size, and composition within limits set by the company.">Version or Model:</label>
                        32-0044
                        <br>
                        <label class="device-attribute-label" href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Whether the device is currently offered for sale by the device company. A device no longer in commercial distribution may or may not still be available for purchase in the marketplace.">Commercial Distribution Status:</label>
                        In Commercial Distribution
                        <br>
                        <label class="device-attribute">Catalog Number:</label>
                        32-0044
                        <br>
                        <label class="device-attribute">Company Name:</label>
                        CAREFUSION 2200, INC
                    </div>
```

I have to retrieve parent text like "Snowden-Pencer", "32-0044","CAREFUSION 2200, INC" individually

This is what I have tried

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]//div[1]/*"))
    )
```

Output is:

```
output = Brand Name:
```

I need to find the correct XPath.
Please help me out, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're using selenium you can use the `getText()` method so it will perhaps look like `driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("XPath")).getText()` Altought that's for Java.

For python I believe it looks something like this

`value_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPath").text`

Comment: I am actually looking for the correct XPath. What do I need to do?

Comment: You right click the item you want the XPath of then press "Inspect" in the editor you right click -> hover over "Copy" -> Copy XPath or Copy full XPath

Comment: I am getting a timeout exception..maybe i should use custom xPath?

Comment: Full XPath's are rather fragile so test using just XPath you can also test to increase the wait time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below two xpaths

```
//label[@rel='toltip']/*
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex

```
import re
a = """<div class="xsmall-12 medium-6 columns">
                        <label class="device-attribute-label" rel="tooltip" title="Proprietary/trade name of the medical device as used in the labeling or catalog.">Brand Name:</label>
                        Snowden-Pencer
                        <br>
                        <label class="device-attribute-label" rel="tooltip" title="Identifies a category or design of devices that have specifications, performance, size, and composition within limits set by the company.">Version or Model:</label>
                        32-0044
                        <br>
                        <label class="device-attribute-label" href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Whether the device is currently offered for sale by the device company. A device no longer in commercial distribution may or may not still be available for purchase in the marketplace.">Commercial Distribution Status:</label>
                        In Commercial Distribution
                        <br>
                        <label class="device-attribute">Catalog Number:</label>
                        32-0044
                        <br>
                        <label class="device-attribute">Company Name:</label>
                        CAREFUSION 2200, INC
                    </div>"""
b = re.findall(r' (.*?)\n', a)
c = [x.lstrip().rstrip() for x in b if '<' not in x and '>' not in x]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below,

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

entire_span = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Version or Model:']/..")))

entire_span_splitted = entire_span.get_attribute('innerText').split(":")

#print(entire_span_splitted[0])
print(entire_span_splitted[1])
```

**Output:**

```
Snowden-Pencer
```

**Import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```